# python matplotlib.pyplot doesn't rendering timeseries plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, timeserieschart

`ax.plot()` doesn't render the time series plot, while `pandas.plot()` and `plt.scatter()` works. But because I need to reform my axis, I need to use `ax.plot()`.

My data:

[image]

When I try to plot it:
`ax=df_cuba['ORD'].plot()`

It works perfectly:

[image]

But when I try to use :
`plt.plot(x=df_cuba.index,y=df_cuba['ORD'])`

It shows nothing:

[image]

It also works for `scatterplot`.

I couldn't find any posts about this. I suspect the `py.plot` is trying a different way to plot time series data.

Comment: You are probably `plt.show()` after the plots.

Comment: Thanks, but it also does not change the result.

Answer (score 0):

`plot` does not have named `x` and `y` arguments. So suppose you have `xdata` and `ydata` you want to plot, you cannot use <strike>`plt.plot(x=xdata, y=ydata)`</strike>, but instead need

```
plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
```

For scatter this is different, here you can use both

```
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata)
plt.scatter(x=xdata, y=ydata)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but `plt.plot(x,y)` does not change the results.

Comment: It sure does. I explained the reason in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

I found out the real reason: `plt.plot` can only plot numerical data, so if we want to plot the time series data with `np.datetime64` or `pd.datetime` format, we need to use the following command:

```
plt.plot_date(date, y)
```

Comment: There isn't even any `date` in the question.